# Confusion about a particular topological basis case

Tags: general-topology

I intuitively understand the concept of a basis for a topology, however I was considering a particular situation that didn't seem to add up. Here it is:

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$. A basis $\mathscr{B}$ can be any collection of subsets of $X$, so let $\mathscr{B} = \left\{\{1, 2, 3\}\right\}$. Every $x \in X$ is also contained in an element of $\mathscr{B}$, namely the only element in $\mathscr{B}$. The only possible intersection within $\mathscr{B}$ is $\{1, 2, 3\} \cap \{1, 2, 3\} = \{1, 2, 3\}$. An arbitrary $x$ that is contained in this intersection is an element of a third $B \in \mathscr{B}$, where $B$ is $\{1, 2, 3\}$ once again. Since $\{1, 2, 3\}\subseteq\{1, 2, 3\}$, all the axioms for a basis are satisfied.

Now my question is: How could this basis possibly construct $\varnothing$, which is required for any topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $X$? The only mistakes I could think of were that $\varnothing$ must be in the basis or that there must be a distinct third $B \in \mathscr{B}$ that satisfies the intersection axiom. However, the definition of a basis in Munkres does not point these things out. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: A basis cannot be any collection of subsets. Instead, it must (1) cover the whole set and (2) for any $A,B \in \mathscr B$, the intersection $A \cap B$ must be a union of some elements of $\mathscr B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that any collection of subsets of $X$ is the base for a topology on $X.$

If $T$ is a topology on $X$ and $B\subset T$ then $B$ is called a base for $T$ iff every  $t\in T$ is equal to $\cup U$ for some $U\subset B.$ (This include the case $U=\phi.$)

If $C$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ then $C$ is the base for a topology on $X$ iff

(i): $\forall p\in X\;\exists s\in C\;(x\in c).$ (Every $p\in X$ belongs to at least one member of $C.$),

AND (ii):  Whenever $c_1,c_2\in C$  and $p\in c_1\cap c_2,$ there exists $c_3\in C$  with $p\in c_3\subset c_1\cap c_2.$

Condition (ii) is necessary because  if $C$ is a base for a topology $T$ then $c_1,c_2\in T$, so $p\in c_1\cap c_2\in T$ so $c_1\cap c_2=\cup U$ for some $U\subset C$, so  $p$ must belong to some $c_3\in U.$

BTW. If $B$ is a base for the topology $T$ and $t\in T$ then $t$ might be represented as  the union of members of $B$ in many different ways. That is, there may be many different $U\subset T$ such that $\cup U=t.$

Comment: Given this definition, would the basis that I mentioned above actually be a basis for the trivial topology? Or must $\emptyset\in\mathscr{B}$?

Comment: $\phi\in B$ is allowed but unnecessary . For the case $\phi=U\subset B$ we have $\cup U=\cup \phi =\phi$  so $\phi$ is the union of a subset of $B.$ In patricular the empty space $X=\phi$ has two bases: $\phi$ and $\{\phi\}$.... And yes, $\{X\} $is a base for the "trivial" (a.k.a , the coarse, or anti-discrete) topology ) on $X$.

Comment: I see now. So $\emptyset$ vacuously satisfies the requirements for a subset of $X$ to be open. Therefore, you can assume that $\emptyset\in\mathscr{B}$ which then allows you to construct $\emptyset$ in any generated topology by simply taking the union of $\emptyset$ with itself. I can think of $\emptyset$ as an inherent element of all bases. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: $\phi$ is not necessarily a member of a base, and if $B$ is a base for the topology $T$ then so is $B$ \ $\{\phi\}.$ .... In your Q, $B=\{X\}$ is a base  and $\phi \not \in B.$..... However it is a part of the def'n of a topology  that $\phi$ is a member of every topology.

Comment: I understand that $\emptyset$ must be a member of every topology, but how do I go from not having $\emptyset$ in $\mathscr{B}$ to having $\emptyset$ in a topology $\mathscr{T}$ generated by $\mathscr{B}$? This is where my confusion lies.

Comment: If $U$ is ANY subset of $B$ then $\cup U\in T.$  Including the case when $U=\phi.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the empty set as the union of NO member of $\mathcal{B}.$ Otherwise, just assume that in the concept of basis $\emptyset \in \mathcal{B}.$

Comment: So in reality, $\mathscr{B} = \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \varnothing\}$?

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathcal{B}$ to be a base for a topology $\mathcal{T}$ it is necessary and sufficient that

$$\forall O \in \mathcal{T}: \forall x \in O: \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \subseteq O$$

This certainly holds for $O = \{1,2,3\}$ (for any $x$ take $B = \{1,2,3\}$) and *also* for $O = \emptyset$ (as any "for all" statement over the empty set is true). So $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ is a base for the topology $\{\emptyset, \{1,2,3\}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A topology always includes $\emptyset $, [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Topology.html).  What you have there is a *subbase*.  Any collection of subsets of X is a subbase (and generates a basis...). By adding  $\emptyset  $ to your set you get  $\{\{1, 2, 3\},\emptyset\}$, the *trivial* *topology* on X.

Comment: Are you implying that the basis must be a topology itself? Your answer seems to contradict what others are telling me...

Comment: No the basis doesn't have to be a topology itself;  but it is in the case of the trivial topology.